# Count down timer with circular progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-shapes

I created an countdown timer. I got a border which is made circular. As the timer is tending towards zero, the circular border should change color with decrement in the seconds.

[I created the JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/th190c7a/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-timer">0.00</button>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
var displayminutes;
var displayseconds;
var initializeTimer = 1.5 // enter in minutes
var minutesToSeconds = initializeTimer*60;

$("#document").ready(function(){
    setTime = getTime();
    $(".btn-timer").html(setTime[0]+":"+setTime[1])
});


$(".btn-timer").click(function(){
    var startCountDownTimer = setInterval(function(){
          minutesToSeconds = minutesToSeconds-1;
        var timer = getTime();
         $(".btn-timer").html(timer[0]+":"+timer[1]);
        if(minutesToSeconds == 0){
            clearInterval(startCountDownTimer);
            console.log("completed");
        }
      },1000)
});


function getTime(){

    displayminutes = Math.floor(minutesToSeconds/60);
    displayseconds = minutesToSeconds - (displayminutes*60);
    if(displayseconds < 10)
    {   
        displayseconds ="0"+displayseconds;
    }
     if(displayminutes < 10)
    {   
        displayminutes = "0"+displayminutes;
    }

    return [displayminutes, displayseconds];
}
```

How do I a get a circular progress bar. I looked for some jQuery plugin but they are not matching my requirement. I am looking for an output similar [to this link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Round-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-For-jQuery/)

Comment: I had created [this pen](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/details/bdpKKq/) sometime back. Does it look similar to what you need? The outer solid border can be removed.

Comment: You could also have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350504/circular-percent-progress-bar). The thing with both the suggested links is that they don't look like the color is filling up an existing gray area like in your link.

Comment: I would better stick to your codepen. I couldnt identify the middle part code. Which line of your code is displaying 1-100 in the circle.

Comment: Sorry. Long break this week. I will work it out today and keep you posted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is a  sample snippet for the countdown timer with a circular progress bar that changes color as the value comes down.

Basically what we are doing is the follows: (refer inline comments in code for more details)

- 4 additional `div` are absolutely positioned on top of the parent. Each represents a quadrant.
- Initially the skew angle on all of them is 0 degree, so they are all fully visible and cover the entire parent. This hides the `box-shadow` of the parent and thus makes it look like a solid circle.
- At every iteration, we modify the skew angle of each quadrant (`div`) such that the quadrants eventually become invisible one by one and thus revealing the `box-shadow` of parent.
- The quadrants become invisible when the skew angle reaches +/- 90 degrees and so at each iteration the angle is calculated as **(90deg / no. of steps covered in that quadrant)**.
- As the progress moves past one quadrant to another, the `box-shadow` of the parent is changed to give the appearance of the progress bar changing its color.
- The original CodePen uses the `data-progress` attribute's value directly as the `content` of a pseudo-element. But that value gets incremented with every iteration. Since it is also used in calculation of the skew angles, I have left it as-is and used a separate field for the countdown timer. Content of pseudo-elements cannot be set using JS and so I have added another `div` for the timer text.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
    quad1 = document.querySelector('.quad1'),
    quad2 = document.querySelector('.quad2'),
    quad3 = document.querySelector('.quad3'),
    quad4 = document.querySelector('.quad4'),
    counter = document.querySelector('.counter');

  var progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 1000); // call function every second

  function incrementProg() {
    progress = progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress'); //get current value
    progress++; // increment the progress bar value by 1 with every iteration
    progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', progress); //set value to attribute
    counter.textContent = 100 - parseInt(progress, 10); // set countdown timer's value
    setPie(progress); // call the paint progress bar function based on progress value
    if (progress == 100) {
      clearInterval(progInc); // clear timer when countdown is complete
    }
  }

  function setPie(progress) {
    /* If progress is less than 25, modify skew angle the first quadrant */
    if (progress <= 25) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + progress * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
    }

    /* Between 25-50, hide 1st quadrant + modify skew angle of 2nd quadrant */
    else if (progress > 25 && progress <= 50) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 25) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px orange'); 
    }

    /* Between 50-75, hide first 2 quadrants + modify skew angle of 3rd quadrant */
    else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 75) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + (progress - 50) * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px yellow');
    }

    /* Similar to above for value between 75-100 */
    else if (progress > 75 && progress <= 100) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 3rd completely
      quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 75) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px green');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: beige;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px red;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.counter {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
}
div > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.quad1,
.quad4 {
  top: 0%;
}
.quad2,
.quad3 {
  top: 50%;
}
.quad1,
.quad3 {
  transform: skew(0deg); /* invisible at -90deg */
}
.quad2,
.quad4 {
  transform: skewY(0deg); /* invisible at 90deg */
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
}
div[data-progress] {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div data-progress="0">
  <div class="quad1"></div>
  <div class="quad2"></div>
  <div class="quad3"></div>
  <div class="quad4"></div>
  <div class='counter'>100</div>
</div>
```

---

In the below snippet, I have added a different `background` for each quadrant to provide a better visual illustration of what exactly is happening.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
    quad1 = document.querySelector('.quad1'),
    quad2 = document.querySelector('.quad2'),
    quad3 = document.querySelector('.quad3'),
    quad4 = document.querySelector('.quad4'),
    counter = document.querySelector('.counter');

  var progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 1000); // call function every second

  function incrementProg() {
    progress = progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress'); //get current value
    progress++; // increment the progress bar value by 1 with every iteration
    progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', progress); //set value to attribute
    counter.textContent = 100 - parseInt(progress, 10); // set countdown timer's value
    setPie(progress); // call the paint progress bar function based on progress value
    if (progress == 100) {
      clearInterval(progInc); // clear timer when countdown is complete
    }
  }

  function setPie(progress) {
    /* If progress is less than 25, modify skew angle the first quadrant */
    if (progress <= 25) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + progress * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
    }

    /* Between 25-50, hide 1st quadrant + modify skew angle of 2nd quadrant */
    else if (progress > 25 && progress <= 50) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 25) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px orange');
    }

    /* Between 50-75, hide first 2 quadrants + modify skew angle of 3rd quadrant */
    else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 75) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + (progress - 50) * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px yellow');
    }

    /* Similar to above for value between 75-100 */
    else if (progress > 75 && progress <= 100) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 3rd completely
      quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 75) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px green');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: beige;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px red;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.counter {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
}
div > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.quad1, .quad4{
  top: 0%;
}
.quad2, .quad3{
  top: 50%;
}
.quad1, .quad3{
  transform: skew(0deg);
}
.quad2, .quad4{
  transform: skewY(0deg);
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
}
div[data-progress] {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.quad1 {
  background: blue;
}
.quad2 {
  background: pink;
}
.quad3 {
  background: tan;
}
.quad4 {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div data-progress="0">
  <div class="quad1"></div>
  <div class="quad2"></div>
  <div class="quad3"></div>
  <div class="quad4"></div>
  <div class='counter'>100</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ! awesome gradient , absolutly love it , where do u get these coller pallets from lol .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: That's an attempt to make sure that the background doesn't grab more attention than the actual answer :P (I am poor at choosing colors).

Comment: I am working with svg as per client's advise. But your input was most valuable. I need to travel a lot.