# CSS Circle with border

Tags: css, css-shapes

Every guide I find has the line and fill the same colour. All I want is a circle with a red line and white fill.

I have tried:

```
.circle {
    border: red;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius:75px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

But cannot get the red border?

Comment: where do you want the red line to show up? consider adding your html as well

Answer (score 76):

You forgot to set the width of the border! Change `border: red;` to `border:1px solid red;`

Here the full code to get the circle:

```css
.circle {
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid red;    
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 36):

You are missing the [border width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width) and the [border style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) properties in the [Border shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) :

```css
.circle {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

---

Also, You can use percentages for the border-radius property so that the value isn't dependent of the circle width/height. That is why I used 50% for border-radius (more info on [border-radius in pixels and percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px-or-em)).

*Side note : In your example, you didn't specify the border-radius property without vendor prefixes, you propably don't need them as only browsers before chrome 4 safari 4 and Firefox 3.6 use them (see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)).*

Comment: Hey, any chance one can control the red outline a little bit more? let me explain. I don't want to show the red outline as a full circle but rather have some parameter that controls how much of it shows. Think for example some % use case. 25% would show 3/4 of the red line, 50% would show half the circle etc.

Comment: @sOltan with this approach, it is diofficult to control the outline as you intend to. I suggest you check out svg for that. Here is an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350504/circular-percent-progress-bar

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```css
.circle {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-weight:600;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://jsbin.com/qamuyajipo/3/edit?html,output

```
.circle {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius:75px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for editing @sebastianbrosch i wrote too much markdown recently :)

Comment: @web-tiki nuh.. i just keep the minimal change

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgv59tdh/) so you can see an example of this working.

HTML code:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS code:

```css
.circle {
        /*This creates a 1px solid red border around your element(div) */
        border:1px solid red;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        height: 100px;
        /* border-radius 50% will make it fully rounded. */
        border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius:50%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='circle'></div>
```