# SVG percent animation do not work in safari and chrome

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I am trying to create a percent circle, and the percent circle is always at 100% and not increasing like it should be. Is this chrome problem?

```
var count = $(('#count'));
              $({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
                duration: 5000,
                easing: 'linear',
                step: function () {
                  count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
                }
              });
              var s = Snap('#animated');
var progress = s.select('#progress');

progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hn6mbqwv/

Comment: What is the meaning of "prosent"? I assume it's a typo for something but I'm afraid I can't work it out.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't load the jQuery library (or the snap library btw) as it should like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29512804/1811992) (which you could have provided credit too)

Comment: Sorry I misstype. It was percent circle.